# How is $\delta s$ different than $ds$?

Tags: notation, differentiation

Specifically I'm reading Dirac's General Relativity and he says essentially:

$$ \delta Q = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x^\mu} \delta x^\mu $$

But what's the difference between this and:

$$ dQ = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x^\mu} d x^\mu $$

From what I understand this is some kind of variational calculus thing, but I don't explicitly know, it seems completely identical.

Here's the context in which I am reading it from if it helps at all:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153791/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate, my answer was contained within this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/153808/59282 specifically this portion: http://prntscr.com/7i4xe2 . It's incredibly hard to search for something when it's called "delta x" and you don't know much else about it haha.