# Why is $dm$ and $\Delta m$ used this way in physics textbooks?

Tags: notation, calculus

I would assume that $\Delta m$ would mean a finite change in mass and $dm$ to be an infinitesimal change in mass. But many physics textbooks use it to denote a small but finite mass and an infinitesimal mass element respectively while writing a differential equation. Why? And how does this make sense?

Similarly, $dU$, which should mean the infinitesimal change in the potential energy function is treated as the "small" potential energy of mass $dm$. Same for $dF$ etc.

One e.g would be to look at the derivation of the gravitational potential energy of a point mass and a shell. The potential energy of the ring is changed from $U_i$ to $dU$ and the mass of the ring is taken as $dM$. Doesn't $d$ mean an infinitesimal *change* in some quantity?

Comment: In rocket, $\Delta m$ refers to mass change due to gas propulsion.  In calculating C.G. or moment of inertia, $dm$ means finite mass.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70376/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92925/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between $\Delta$, $d$ and $\delta$](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/)

Comment: No that is not what I'm asking. I know the difference between $\delta m$ and $dm$. I just want to know why $dm$ is regarded as a very small mass rather than an infinitesimal change in mass, and so on for $dU$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

You must always consider the specific notation definitions which an author may use. There is not a unique use of Δm. The notation dm is closer to being a universal notation for an infinitesimal m element, although m might be defined as something other than mass. Pay attention to context and book definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The way they use the $dm$ (or $dU$ or $dF$) notations is to represent an infinitesimal element.

You seem to be getting it confused with rates of change, given by $\frac{dm}{dt}$ for example.

When it is a ratio, then you are determining the change in $m$ as a function of $t$.  $dm$ still represents an infinitesimal mass, but $\frac{dm}{dt}$ can be used to find the change in mass relative to time at any time (t).  The two infinitesimals themselves don't represent a change, but by comparing the ratio of the two infinitesimals as a parameter changes, you can determine the rate of change with respect to another variable.