# $\delta$ differential notation

Tags: notation, differentiation

Various textbooks that I am currently consulting (including Spacecraft Dynamics and Control An Introduction - Anton H.J. De Ruiter | Christopher J. Damaren | James R. Forbes Section 1.4, page 32) use $\delta$, not $d$ or $\partial$ to express an infinitesimal quantity. In the context of the reference text above, the symbol is used as part of a general definition for the derivative of a vector. Specifically, given

$$\mathbf{\vec{r}}=\mathcal{\vec{F^{T}_{1}}}\mathbf{\vec{r_{1}}}$$

where

$$\mathcal{\vec{F^{T}_{1}}}$$

is a vectrix

$$[\mathbf{\vec{x_1}} \phantom{s} \mathbf{\vec{y_1}} \phantom{s} \mathbf{\vec{z_1}}].$$

The time derivative of the vector is defined as

$$\dot{\mathbf{\vec{r}}}\triangleq \lim_{\delta t\to 0}\frac{\delta\mathbf{\vec{r}}}{\delta t}.$$

In this context, what is the difference between $\frac{\delta\mathbf{\vec{r}}}{\delta t}$ and $\frac{d \mathbf{\vec{r}}}{d t}$ ?

Note about thermodynamic use of $\delta$: My understanding is that $\delta$ is used in thermodynamic equations to express path dependence of a scalar quantity such as heat or work. What does it mean in the context of an abstract physical vector?

Comment: Oh snap, that's a delta my bad.  Anyways, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317338/402453 that should explain it.  The second answer gives a good physics answer.  I've seen it in the context that answer talks about.

Comment: I have updated the question to address your comments. Thank you @JMac for the link to the other question. However, I am afraid it did not answer my question as I am interested in the notation in the context of physical vectors, not thermodynamics quantities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Typically, $\frac{d}{d(\ldots)}$ is a [(total) derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative), $\frac{\partial}{\partial(\ldots)}$ is a [partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative), and $\frac{\delta}{\delta(\ldots)}$ is a [functional/variational derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative). See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153791/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/2451) Phys.SE posts and links therein.
2. In Ref. 1 the symbol $\frac{d\mathbf{\vec{r}}}{d t}$ denotes the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative), while $\frac{\delta\mathbf{\vec{r}}}{\delta t}$ denotes the [difference quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient). A more common notation for the latter is $\frac{\Delta\mathbf{\vec{r}}}{\Delta t}$.

References:

1. A.H.J. De Ruiter, C.J. Damaren & J.R. Forbes, *Spacecraft Dynamics and Control: An Introduction;* Section 1.4, p. 32.

Comment: I agree that, in the context above, the difference quotient would make sense. However, I have seen in $Dynamics$ by Ginsburg and Genin (old textbook) an example of an angular momentum framework that used $\delta$, and when solving problems with that framework, it seemed $\frac{\delta \vec{r}}{\delta t}$ was functionally equivalent to a total derivative. I think the framework was: $\frac{\delta \vec{H}}{\delta t} + \vec{r} \times m\vec{v} = \vec{\tau}$

Comment: Which page in [Ginsburg & Genin](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=ginsberg+genin+dynamics)?

Comment: Page 829 equation 25

Comment: Wiley (1977) only has 558 pages.

Comment: The equation is $\sum\vec{M_{A}} = \vec{\dot{H_A}} = \frac{\delta\vec{\dot{H_A}}}{\delta t} + \vec{\omega} \times \vec{H_A}$

Comment: I think there might be two different parts to it because my copy starts at chapter 10 and page 381

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the book.

Comment: My guess is that it is the variational derivative, but I don't really have a firm reason for such a statement. The more I looked into this notation, the muddier and more ambiguous it got. Thanks for your help anyway.