# What is $\delta t$?

Tags: conventions, notation, differentiation, mathematics

I'm confused whether it's difference between two times (i.e final and initial) or it represents very small time.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Difference between $Δ$, $d$ and $δ$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/84967).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between $\Delta$, $d$ and $\delta$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/)

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153791/25301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\delta t$ represents the change in a time period.  As to whether it needs to be a small time period, no.

Comment: Then what is dt ?

Comment: dt would be the change in time.  But you usually have do over something, like dt/ds, where s is displacement

Comment: @user182794 please mark the tick if it helps.