# What is $δx$ used in physics?

Tags: conventions, notation, differentiation

I know that:

1) Change in $x$ ie., $Δx$, when $\lim Δx→0$, then $Δx$ is replaced by $dx$.

2) I also know that $∂x$ is used in partial derivative.

Then what is $δx$?
Is $dx$ and $δx$ is just the same or something different. I want some mathematical explanation.

Comment: It all depends on the context. As much as we want to believe, there is not a universal mathematical notation for certain things. Please give the context as to where this occurs so others can answer the question in the best way possible.

Comment: As Aaron said, it really depends on the context, but I have seen many times δx just as a fancy way to write dx (yes, they are the same, which I think is your doubt).

Comment: It depends, but one widespread usage of the $\delta$ convention is in calculus of variations problems.

Comment: Is it really that dx and δx is just the same and nothing more?

Comment: Every book has its own nomenclature, so you should see that for your purpose. For example, Cengel uses δx for showing inexact differentials.

Comment: It would be easier if you provide an example, a formula where you have seen this notation and you are not sure about the meaning. I would be temped to say that dx and δx are the same things most of the cases, but you also have functions like the Kronecker delta which use that symbol.

Comment: @RoshanLeyangi They can be the same, or they cannot be the same. *It all depends on the context*. Please supply that context so we can answer the question.

Comment: @AaronStevens Do you have any example.

Comment: To what specific person does the pronoun "he" refer?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/2451 and links therein.

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153791/25301

Comment: @RoshanLeyangi My examples don't matter. The context you are using does.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I've seen "$\delta x$" to mean a tiny change in $x$, without necessarily invoking all of the mathematical machinery of a derivative. In a derivation, you might start with variables $ \delta x $ and $\delta t$ as ordinary quantities, and then later put in an explicit step that takes the limits as they approach $0$.