# Why do they specify the differential of Work using an lowercase delta $\delta W$, instead of $dW$

Tags: work, differentiation, notation, calculus

I was curious, why do they specify the differential of Work using an lowercase delta symbol $\delta$ as in  "$\delta W$", instead of using a $d$, as in $dW$.  For example:

$$\delta W=\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}$$

Does that have anything to do with the idea of **absolute differentiation** from tensor calculus?  Example:

$$\frac{\delta T^i}{\delta t} = \frac{dT^i}{dt} + \Gamma^i_{rs} T^r \frac{dx^s}{dt}$$

If I convert this formula into a **absolute differential**, by multiplying both sides by $\delta t$, then I get:

$$\delta T^i = dT^i + \Gamma^i_{rs} T^r dx^s$$

I would interpret this to mean that if you are using Cartesian coordinates then $\delta T^i = dT^i$ since the christoffel symbols of the second kind $\Gamma^i_{rs}$ are all zero for Cartesian coordinates.

I was just curious if this has a similar means for the physics formula:

$$\delta W=\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}$$

how would you apply this formula in cylindrical coordinates instead of Cartesian coordinates for example.

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)  where i found the formula for work differential)

---

If I look in my tensor book i find that the christoffel symbols of the second kind for cylinderical coordinates:

$\Gamma^r = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0 \\ 0&-r&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

$\Gamma^\theta = \begin{bmatrix}0& 1/r&0 \\ 1/r &0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\Gamma^{z} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$

so in this case the absolute differential would have a none zero second term.

---

Another possibility that using under case $\delta$ as in $\delta W$ has nothing to do with absolute differentiation because work is a scalar?

**I just was wondering if it is somehow linked to $\delta$ absolution differentiation operator in tensors class...**

---

The textbook i'm looking at says nothing about tensors... but it does tell me that if you are using cylindrical coordinates then the formula for a differential is different which sounds very tensor like to me.  Example:

$ds = dr \frac{ds}{dr} + r~d\theta \frac{ds}{d\theta} + dz \frac{ds}{dz}$

Normally, in Cartesian coordinates the formula for a differential would be:

$ds = \frac{\partial s}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial s}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial s}{\partial z}dy$

Comment: Usually one calls it *lowercase*, rather than "under case".

Comment: Not a definitive answer, sorry, but I was taught that dW makes one think that W is a real thing that you can talk about changing: “dW is an infinitesimal change in work”, which is wrong. the deltaW is meant to be a reminder of “an infinitesimal bit of work”

Comment: I asked a similar question a few years ago about the difference between various symbols for "change" or "difference" in the context of derivatives: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153791/. Maybe the answers there can give some hints?

Comment: I thought it just meant it depends on the path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between $\Delta$, $d$ and $\delta$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/)