# How a 'variation' $\delta x$ of an independent parameter differs from $dx$?

Tags: differentiation, notation, variational-calculus

I have been reading the Classical Field theory part from The Quantum field theory book of Lewis H Ryder.
After defining classical field $\phi(x^\mu)$ he says something about adding variations on both the field, and the coordinates. $$\phi(x^{\mu}) \longrightarrow \phi(x^{\prime\mu})=\phi(x^{\mu})+\delta\phi(x^{\mu})$$
$$x^{ \mu}\longrightarrow  x^{\prime \mu}=x^{ \mu}+\delta x^{ \mu} $$
Now, my question is how this $\delta x$ is different from $dx$? Clearly $\delta x$ is not just an infinitesimal number like $dx$. How does a **Variation** defined in such an independent variable $x$? What is exactly the definition of $variation - \delta$?

Comment: *There is no such thing  as an infinitasimal number.* If there was, you could take half of it and have a *more* infinitesimal number.

Comment: @GyroGearloose https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis

Comment: @Daniel I know, but is physics based on that?

Comment: @GyroGearloose Then what is $\delta x$ here? and How does it differ from dx ?

Comment: @BaibhabBose I have studies maths but nowhere saw a sound and rigid definition. I'm myself curios of the answers here. As for the $dx$ it is just a symbol used in derivatives and integrals. From math point of view all boils down on taking limits.

Comment: To reopen this question (v2), consider to give your definition of $dx$.

Comment: @Qmechanic physics and maths people use same symbols with different meanings. *My* interpretation of $dx$ for any expression like $f(dx)$ is to replace it with $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}f(\epsilon)$.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153791/2451 and links therein.

Comment: "Closed. This question needs details or clarity." Of course, I guess that's the main reason the OP posted it. There have been more  questions about "infinitesimal" values and such shortly, and the way physics use math is, quite, astonishing.