# Does the expression "$^2$..." mean the same thing as "$\Delta ^2$... "?

Tags: space-expansion, conventions, differentiation, notation, calculus

I reviewed [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/) but sometimes I'm unsure about delta versus differential notation.
Does the expression "$ds^2=-c^2dt^2+a^2(t)[dr^2 + S_k^2(r)d\Omega^2 ]$" mean the same thing as
"$\Delta s^2=-c^2\Delta t^2+a^2(t)[\Delta r^2 + S_k^2(r)\Delta \Omega^2 ]$"
? It seems like it may, but my understanding is that the former may be more appropriate for infinitesimal distance.

Comment: I'd say that the other question/answers you reviewed is pretty comprehensive and informative. In general, the prefix $d$ usually means an (exact) infinitesimal change and the prefix $\Delta$ simply means change that is not _necessarily_ infinitesimal. Though you are right to ask since many authors are sloppy and abuse this notation/use them interchangeably.

Comment: Of course anyone can use any notation for anything, but for most people $\Delta s$ is a small real number and $ds$ is a cotangent vector.

Answer (score 5):

The first one is exact, but the second would be an approximation for a non-infinitesimal (i.e. finite) interval.