# Does this particular notation for derivatives imply anything in particular?

Tags: differentiation, notation, mathematics, functional-derivatives

In some physics textbooks (and in those of other sciences that use physics, like soil science), I've seen some derivatives written as:

$$\frac{\delta f}{\delta t} $$

Which is a bit strange. Does this notation imply anything different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symbols of derivatives](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153791/) See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/). In general, it's "hollow words" without a precise definition.

Comment: It can mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative); we'd have to see the context in which you saw it to know if that's what's meant, but my guess is it isn't.