What's the difference between $dx$ and $\delta x$?
In the process of defining crystal momentum $\hbar k$, I found these formulas below.
By the definition of group velocity,
$$v_g=\frac{d\omega_{nk}}{dk}=\frac{1}{\hbar}\frac{dE_{nk}}{dk}$$
Also if an electron is in the electric field, it'll get the electric force $F$.
(Idk why but) The group velocity $v_g$ is actually same with the real velocity of classical particle so,
$$\delta E=Fv_g\delta t$$
Comparing two formulas, below holds.
$$\delta E=\frac{dE_{nk}}{dk}\delta k=\hbar v_g\delta k$$
Then we can find that
$$\frac{d(\hbar k)}{dt}=F$$
Here, I'm confusing why we should use the notation $\delta$ here. (for $t$, $k$ and $E$)
I thought $\delta$ could be differed from $d$ for two ways,

Inexact differential
Calculus of variations

But I think here $\delta$ is not used for both purposes.
Actually, $\delta E$ might be the calculus of variations, but in case of $t$, it's not even a funtional.
Also in case of inexact differential, they should be path dependent - I think $t$ couldn't be.
Actually, if it was $\delta E = F\delta s$, then I could just ignore this(it might be some notation for one of two above) - But I can't just ignore $\delta s = v_g\delta t$. Why it's not $v_gdt$ instead?
At the end, $\frac{\delta k}{\delta t}$ becomes $\frac{dk}{dt}$. This confuses me more.
Why they use $\delta$ notation here instead of $d$?
I slightly heard that in physics, we use two notations for differential forms, differs by possibility of precise measurement, but I have no idea for that. I couldn't find any information.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153791/2451 More on notation for differentials.

"In the process of defining crystal momentum, I found these formulas below" Since you are asking about specific instances of formulae, please provide the source where you found them and include the relevant paragraphs. Otherwise, your question lacks context.

Why do you think there is a difference between the two notations here?

http://physica.gnu.ac.kr/phtml/modern/solidstate/kronigpenney/kronigpenney5.html I found those here. I thought there should be some difference or why use the notation delta instead of d?
