# What is the meaning of $d$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, time, conventions, notation, differentiation

[image]

What is the meaning of $d$? Is is *Delta*? If it is *Delta*, why is it then not $\Delta$? I am still confused with that. Can someone help explain it to me?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative, or for more basic info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative

Comment: I asked a question about this a few years ago: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153791/ There is a good answer there with a detailed list of many such closely related symbols. Basically, $\mathrm d$ and $\Delta$ both mean **a difference** in a quantity. $\mathrm d$ just means an **infinitely small** difference.

Comment: You need to take up differential calculus.

Comment: In words $\frac{d}{dt}$ means "rate of change with respect to time". So in words Newton's Second Law is "force ($\vec F$) is the rate of change of momentum ($\vec p$) with respect to time". The equation is a more concise and more precise way of stating this.

Answer (score 1):

While it's more on the mathematical side, [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function) should answer your question in more detail (or [also here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_calculus)

For physicist, $d/dt$ is the time derivative of a quantity, $\vec{p}$ in your case. So what your formula says is that "force $\vec{F}$ is the time derivative (the change over time) of momentum $\vec{p}$".

This is somewhat related to Delta ($\Delta$). For linear functions, one can calculate the slope $s$ via "rise over run",
$$
s = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}
$$
If your function is not linear, you can still approximate the slope for a short section with this. To get more accurate results, you can shorten your Delta. In the limit of $\Delta \to 0$, you get the differential mentioned in the Wiki article. Mathematically, the slope at point $x_0$ is then also called the **derivative** of $f$ at $x_0$
$$
s = f'(x_0) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+\Delta x) - f(x_0)}{\Delta x}
$$
So, the force $\vec{F}$ is the time derivative of your momentum $\vec{p}$,
$$
\vec{F}=\frac{d \vec{p}}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \vec{p}
$$
EDIT: so, what the answer to the question "what is the meaning of $d$?" should probably be is: if you make your $\Delta$ really, really small (infinitesimally small, to be precise), you get $d$.

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dt}\vec{p}$$
So $d$ = $\Delta$?

Comment: Have you taken calculus before? $d \neq \Delta$, they don't mean the same thing as symbols. It's a limit from the discrete to the continuous.

Comment: I haven't studied calculus.