# Meaning of the $\delta$ notation

Tags: differentiation, notation

Two examples I've seen of this so far are in statistical mechanics, when looking at the work done on a system:

$$dW=-\frac{1}{\beta}\frac{\partial \ln{Z}}{\partial V}\delta V$$

and in the Noether charge:

$$Q(t)\equiv \frac{\partial L}{\partial q'_{i}}\delta q_{i}$$

Why use the $\delta$ and not just $dV$ and $dq_{i}$?

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153791/25301