# Non-differential total exact element notation question

Tags: thermodynamics, notation, differentiation, history

I have questions regarding the notation in thermodynamics books of "d bar" (instead of delta) for the non-differential total exact elements like for work $\delta W$.

- When did it appear?
- Where are they used? Are they used worldwide?
- Does it sometimes happen that it is used for non-thermodynamics books? (other fields)

This notation is equivalent to the delta one, and it looks like $\hbar$ with a $d$ insead of the $h$.

Edit : Some people say it's equivalent to this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428173/differential-notation-reference-question) that I also wrote. But here I am asking about the history of the notation that is for thermodynamics, not the Dolbeaut cohomology notation.

Comment: Non-differential? Do you not mean inexact?

Comment: @Emil I mean "non-dte" with dte meaning "differential total exact".

Comment: I'm not really sure what this is about. Are you asking about the history and popularity of a piece of notation?

Comment: @knzhou Yes, exactly

Comment: Some people bother to use dbar, some don't. In general, it can denote any inexact [differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form). You probably would look a tiny bit more "mathematical" and less "practical" using dbar than $\delta$, but I don't think anybody would really care.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36150/2451

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differential notation reference question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/428173/)

Comment: @Qmechanic I know what the element is, I don't know the exact name in english. I just want to know how it is and was used.

Comment: @knzhou It's literally me who asked the question. And the one who answered it turned out to be mistaking with Dolbeaut differential with the thermodynamics notation.

Comment: @PackSciences If you asked a question and didn't like the answer you got, you shouldn't ask the same question again. Just wait a while, or put a bounty on the original question!

Comment: @PackSciences For what it's worth, I don't see anything wrong with what that person said. You can use either dbar or $\delta$ to denote an inexact differential form. Neither is "wrong" or "outdated". And both dbar and $\delta$ can mean different things in different contexts. Nobody is going to arrest you for using one or the other.

Comment: @knzhou It's not the same question. Original asked if there was a difference in terms of mathematics. This one is about history. Those two question are clearly unrelated for me.

Comment: If you really care about the history, then it's just off topic anyway. The history of notation used in physics is not physics. You can ask history questions at the History of Science and Math SE instead.

Comment: @knzhou Can you give me references?