# $\delta Q = dU + \delta W$. Why is it $dU$ while others are partial differentials?

Tags: thermodynamics, notation, differentiation

It is the first law of thermodynamics for a very small change in the state of the system.

[image]

It is in Heat thermodynamics and statistical physics by Brij Lal, Dr. N. Subrahmanyam, and P.S. Hemne.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36150/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153791/2451 and links therein.

Comment: For a differential change in state, irrespective of how extensive or tortuous the path between the two neighboring end points, dU is always the same; but delta W and delta Q can vary extensively with path as long as their difference for the various paths is overall  the same.